# Can't filter Pinecone vectorstore using metadata

Tags: python, langchain, pinecone

I get this error when I try to run the code:

```
pinecone.core.client.exceptions.ApiValueError: Unable to prepare type set for serialization"
The error is in line 61, in <module>
    "answer = chain.run(query)".
```

Here's my code:

```
import pdfLoader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
import pinecone
from langchain.chains.query_constructor.base import AttributeInfo
from langchain.retrievers.self_query.base import SelfQueryRetriever
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceInferenceAPIEmbeddings


pdf = "/Users/Fran/Desktop/Trabajo/vectorizer-service/paper.pdf"

pinecone.init(
    api_key="YOUR_API_KEY",
    environment="YOUR_ENVIROMENT"
)

index = pinecone.Index("prueba") 

inference_api_key="YOUR_API_KEY"


embeddings = HuggingFaceInferenceAPIEmbeddings(
    api_key=inference_api_key, model_name="sangmini/msmarco-cotmae-MiniLM-L12_en-ko-ja" #1536 dimension 
)

#embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002")

# for existing index
vectorstore = Pinecone.from_existing_index("prueba", embeddings)

query = "Which are the key observations when designing AlphaCodium flow?"

llm = ChatOpenAI()

retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={
                                                    "k": 1, 
                                                    'filter': {'type':{ "pdf"}, 
                                                               'project':{ "PromptEngineering"},
                                                                'owner_id':{"001"},
                                                                'file_id':{"pdf"}} 
}
                                    )

chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, retriever=retriever,chain_type="stuff")

answer = chain.run(query)
```

I'm trying to filter my `vectorspace` using metadata to ask a specific pdf and then asking to it, and only it, a question.

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when my filter expression in the `as_retriever` call is malformed.  You want it to be a dictionary of key / value pairs like this.

```
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={
    "k": 1,
    'filter': {
        'type': "pdf",
        'project': "PromptEngineering",
        'owner_id': "001",
        'file_id': "pdf"
    }
})
```